# How do I change the port of Prometheus in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus-operator, strimzi, rancher-desktop

Can I change default port of Prometheus or Strimzi Kafka controlplane (both use 9090 by default) to something different, because I need to run both on the same worker node in Kubernetes? I run Prometheus via the Prometheus operator.

I can't find a solution how to change the Prometheus port inside the Prometheus.yaml file.

Comment: You cannot change the 9090 port in Strimzi based Kafka cluster. But why do they need different port? The port 9090 is not exposed on the host or anaything like that.  It is exposed only on the Strimzi managed Pod(s) and Services. So I do not understand how does it conflcit with port 9090 in Prometheus. I run Prometheus and Strimzi on the same node as well without any issues.

Comment: I have a problem when I apply the Prometheus.yaml file that my Kafka brokers start restarting and are never running again, that's why I thought the problem was in the ports.

Comment: I would not expect that to be the issue. But without any configs, logs etc., hard to say of course.